# Append unique entry to array to Parse.com

Tags: parse-platform

I have an array where it will contain an array of usernames.

```
let query = PFQuery(className:"JobPosting")
        query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(JobPostings[CurrentJobID].objectId!) {
            (JobPosting: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                print(error)
            } else if let JobPosting = JobPosting {
                JobPosting.addObjectsFromArray([PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId as! AnyObject], forKey: "rejected") // Adds username to rejected array for the current job posting
                JobPosting.saveInBackground()

                self.updateJob()

            }
        }
```

This code currents appends an username to the rejected array. However there will be duplicates if the user call this method twice. How can i only append to the array if the entry don't exists in the array?

Comment: Place the contents of the array into an NSMutableSet.  Add the new element to the set (which rejects duplicates), then convert the set back to an array using allObjects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `addUniqueObject:forKey:` or `addUniqueObjectsFromArray:forKey:` instead of `addObjectsFromArray:forKey:` and then parse will check for uniqueness for you.